# How to copying bulk document using transactional batch and how it is different with Stored procedure in java

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure-cosmosdb

I have to copy bulk data in the container I was doing that using the stored procedure. now I want to use transactional batch but I am not getting how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[TransactionalBatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/sql/transactional-batch) conceptually is not for Bulk operations, it is meant for you to define a group of operations belonging to the same Partition Key that you want to execute as a unit. In the past, that could only be done through a Stored Procedure. For example, if your Stored Procedure created 10 documents inside, you can create a TransactionalBatch that performs 10 creates and it achieves the same thing. Because all operations share the same transactional scope, if one fails, the entire group fails (they commit all or none).

Bulk on the other hand is about processing a large number of operations trying to leverage all your available throughput (RU/s). The documents processed through Bulk can belong to different Partition Key values and can fail independently (you can send 100K documents and 1K can fail but 99K succeed). Bulk is exposed through `container.executeBulkOperations` on the V4 Java SDK, there is a complete walk through at https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/sql/bulk-executor-java

Comment: One more confusion if i have to do multiple add operation like TransactionalBatch txBatch = TransactionalBatch
      .createTransactionalBatch(new PartitionKey("/txyz")); and in loop i add 100 txBatch.createItemOperation(cust);  operation and run execute the batch .. will it work or it will fail.   what is limit of operation @Matias Quaranta

Comment: 1. The PartitionKey parameter needs to be the **value** of the Partition Key (not the path) for all the documents in the Batch. The limit is 100 items. If you do the loop, then you are creating Batches one after the other, why don't use Bulk instead? 2 TransactionalBatch objects (each with 100 items in them) can succeed or fail independently, I don't understand why you are going with Batch, it seems your case if more for Bulk.

Comment: Hey Matias Quaranta one more thing like if i have to follow bulk one is there any sample code for sync as i can see sample code for async.

Comment: Actully point is i want to acheive that same in a transcation either all should happer or all fail. that the main purpose i am going for batch operation.

Comment: Then you can do this with up to 100 items. Creating 2 TransactionalBatch with 100 items each, one batch can succeed, the other fail. If you have 1000 items, and you create 10 Batches of 100, you cannot make all 10 Batches succeed or all rollback.

Comment: Cool Lets say a scenario . like in this 10 batches mid 2 are failed and i wanted them to process in sequence so after failure I want to rewrite all the documents again like process all 10 batches again.   but as 3 were already been processed in the previous transaction will it will overwrite it?

Comment: If you send 10 batches and the mid 2 failed, the other 8 are correctly committed and completed, the operations in them were done. Processing all 10 batches again will obviously make the 8 that succeeded fail (those operations were already completed. Because these Batches have nothing related to one another, in your case, you would need to retry only the 2 that failed. But at that point, you are just doing what Bulk does. It sounds like you want to have TransactionalBatch but across batches, that is not possible.